Single formula in master sheet to add data from the same cell in newly added sheets - Excel
I am looking for an excel formula for a "total" cell in a single master sheet that adds up values across multiple other sheets. I would like this formula to automatically search all sheets in the file for data within this same cell and provide a total so that new sheets can be added and old sheets deleted without having to manually reference each cell across multiple sheets. I am hoping there is an automated way of doing this?
Thank you!
I have tried to manually create a formula but it is very time consuming and inflexible as sheets change.

Is VBA an option? I'm not aware of a single one time formula that adds new references/arguments as you add sheets to your workbook.

Coding in VBA for me isnt an option unfortunately, but cutting and pasting some code is possible :)

There is way for existing sheets but not for newly added sheets. For that you will be needed VBA coding.

Thank you for your insight. It's saved me a lot of searching!

This is the code I have in a macro at the moment, but it doesnt appear to be updating as the cell remains at zero:
Function SumAcrossSheets(cellAddress As String) As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim total As Double
total = 0
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> Application.Caller.Parent.Name Then
        On Error Resume Next 
        total = total + ws.Range(cellAddress).Value
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next ws

SumAcrossSheets = total

End Function

I have this code working now however it only recalculates when I click inside the cell and hit enter. This is not going to work across many cells. Am I missing some way of ensuring the VBA macro updates live? Thank you!

Let's say the main sheet is Sheet1. Add a sheet after it and name it e.g. First. Add another sheet after all sheets and name it Last. Now hide both sheets. In Sheet1 add a so-called 3D reference e.g. =SUM(First:Last!A1). This still works when sheets after Sheet1 are deleted or added. In the latter case, when manually added, they will 'land' between First and Last.

So turns out =SUM(StartTab:EndTab!A1) is the function I am looking for :)

If you're still interested in a VBA solution, add the vba tag to your question. Also, add the code to your post. BTW, try Application.Volatile in the first line of your code. Another VBA way would be to use the Workbook_SheetChange event if the values are manually entered or the Workbook_SheetCalculate event if formulas. This would fully automate the task (no need to run or use a formula).

@VBasic2008 wow, that's a nice lifehack, didn't know that'd work. Why not post it as answer?

Here is a link to 3D reference posts on SO and to the MSDocs' "Create a 3-D reference to the same cell range on multiple worksheets".

Please update your question to include your need to sum values from the same cell through multiple sheets, so it's helpful for others searching for a similar solution

If you are looking for a formula that you can copy and paste in certain cells in the Master sheet, There is a way of doing that.
Create a Named Range. Go to Formulas-> Define Name . Enter name as sheet_list and value as
=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")

Use the below formula in the Master sheet where you want to have the sum of all numbers calculated from the rest of the sheets in the workbook.
=SUM(N(INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(sheet_list,SEQUENCE(SHEETS()-1,,2))&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(B2),COLUMN(B2)))))

(Make sure your master sheet is placed in the beginning of the workbook.)
Change 'B2' with the reference of the cell that you are pasting in. (eg. if you are pasting it in H5, replace B2 with H5).
Once done, you can copy paste the formula in other cells of master sheet.
